# Backlight broken or not? Dell XPS 13inch

Tags: dell-xps, backlight

curious if anyone knows (or can guess) whether my problem is hardware or software related?

In the attached picture you will notice that I have a dark grey band on the right side of my screen. It suddenly appeared and also occurs when i enter the bios.

If it is hardware related, what would a solution entail?
If you believe it is software related can i try to resolve it myself and how?

thnx
Eelco

Backlight problem?
[image: Backlight problem?]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it happens inside the BIOS, then it's 90% sure a hardware problem.

You can verify where the problem is by using the
<kbd>Print Scroll</kbd> key to capture the screen to the clipboard.
If the gray band is in the image, then the problem is with the
display adapter. If the band is not in the image,
the problem is with the screen.

In both cases, you need to replace the bad hardware.
If the computer is still under warranty - use it.
Otherwise, a professional is required for such a delicate repair job.